# terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsexception

i am new to IOS and Objective C.

I have an issue that i am not able to solve.
I'am working on a branch that should be working since i discarded all changes to a stable version.

Can someone help me ?

**UPDATED LOG**

```
2015-01-20 15:17:26.152 Fizzer[20954:765835] *** Assertion failure in -[DCFizzerClient initRestKit], /Users/thibault/Documents/XcodeIOS/fizzer_iOS/Fizzer/DCFizzerClient.m:1271
2015-01-20 15:17:26.156 Fizzer[20954:765835] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to add persistent store: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134130.)" UserInfo=0x7fa86e4cd550 {URL=file:///Users/thibault/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/26ACA3A0-3481-41B9-97B9-FCAFCB954DA9/data/Containers/Data/Application/D5D583FE-31BF-4818-BA0B-9C1D3AEF1C71/Documents/Fizzer.sqlite, metadata={
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
        Address = <fce9eead 937b65e9 ccef79f4 799101a4 67fc523e 49271f94 52e96916 64ce47e6>;
        Contact = <6fdb20fc 19489704 65bb2e37 2a2527bb b56d1178 205b1341 15587899 c1767595>;
        DraftPostcard = <9f695a96 c965244c e41f3752 9d1bd351 ebfdbc66 4a66eeaa 310ca2d4 e2a03042>;
        Entity = <cb122d10 055b6f51 1220d40e d8db2aec 89042977 c60e56e5 b741a06f d5a356ea>;
        FacebookFriend = <aa26c70f b4309988 5ebf9ba9 335aaab8 e8602a96 4289e2df 9c6dcab7 7f7e048a>;
        FollowerUser = <a91ca4d9 2437260f 73326a9d 8f398f6e 3b7927cc 881beb41 db66643c 832a791b>;
        FollowingUser = <980b4107 13fe89a6 395d8a8d 0ae2af94 de4cb255 d4b2d39e 3420d226 7447ece3>;
        Postcard = <834f0911 32d10487 6f396969 063ab12a fdb284d3 1364ad05 f64f7072 c58368fa>;
        PostcardReceiver = <d225c666 8f1c97f6 9ed9a55e fdefd2c0 d28f30aa 04d7cd9f f09774fd 20adecee>;
        User = <be4d7939 c54e40cf 70c59fc0 d0fa6baf 37c5096d 8f99fce5 8c40b0bb 16d93982>;
        UserRelation = <13b2a8f2 7c45d0d7 e1c87dc5 a0e777d5 4efe884a 696a42ed f4e7351f aaaa2c96>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "8BD60465-3609-480B-805E-1D07F051D14A";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
}, reason=Can't find model for source store}'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107abff35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000107758bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107abfd9a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001052bf5df -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   Fizzer                              0x000000010319537b -[DCFizzerClient initRestKit] + 923
    5   Fizzer                              0x000000010317b93e __30+[DCFizzerClient sharedClient]_block_invoke + 94
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001080357f4 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108022343 dispatch_once_f + 565
    8   Fizzer                              0x000000010317b8b9 +[DCFizzerClient sharedClient] + 89
    9   Fizzer                              0x0000000103152c8b -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 731
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000105f3e475 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 234
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000105f3efbc -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2463
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000105f41d2c -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1350
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000105f40bf2 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    14  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000109a172a3 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001079f553c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001079eb285 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001079eb045 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001079ea486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000105f40669 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000105f43420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    21  Fizzer                              0x00000001031a1303 main + 115
    22  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010806a145 start + 1
    23  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

**UPDATE 2**
After digging a little, i commented this :

```
//  In method - (void)initRestKit
//  NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store: %@", error);
```

Then my log got a little different :

```
2015-01-20 17:49:45.270 Fizzer[21674:810377] *** Assertion failure in -[RKManagedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts], /Users/thibault/Documents/XcodeIOS/fizzer_iOS/Pods/RestKit/Code/CoreData/RKManagedObjectStore.m:307
2015-01-20 17:49:45.274 Fizzer[21674:810377] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot create managed object contexts: The persistent store coordinator does not have any persistent stores. This likely means that you forgot to add a persistent store or your attempt to do so failed with an error.'
```

Comment: can you post the error description not just the stack?  Looks theres a fragment of it in the first line of your post.

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: Hi, i just updated the logs

Comment: Maybe you have change a coredatamodel and re-run application without remove old app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research here is the solution :

Switching branch wasn't the problem. I had conflict with some of my models wicth corrupted the app already installed in my simulator.

All i had to do was remove the app from simulator and install it again.